# Converting from COO to Compressed sparse matrix

Tags: cuda, opencl, sparse-matrix, csr, cusp-library

I wanted CSR files preferably from matrix market for my OpenCL library, I searched a lot for CSR generators in C but didn't get any. I find matrix market formats comfortable since they have defined the functions for read and write. I'm also curious how CUSP library in CUDA C is able to read COO matrix from an .mtx file and can convert it to CSR format. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the code for reading matrices in [`cusp::io`](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/tree/develop/cusp/io).

Before you go reinventing the wheel, you might want to take a look at [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/index.html), which already include OpenCL CSR matrix types, an spMV implementation, and a number of iterative solvers built on that spMV implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right about that. I deployed Vienna and going through the source code